# Getting errors in CoreML (.mlmodel file)?

Tags: swift, io, xcode9, swift4

I using CoreML with Swift 4.0 on Xcode 9 Beta.

I downloaded Inception v3.mlmodel files from WWDC
I get the errors Use of unresolved identifier 'InceptionV3' and Use of undeclared type 'InceptionV3'

And i download some sample projects and also getting same problem with that downloaded projects.

Now what can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`InceptionV3` is auto generated when you drag and drop the `.mlmodel` file to your project. Try remove the reference to that file and drag and drop again. Also ensure the target in `Target Membership` is selected (select the `.mlmodel` and look at the right panel).